# Is using mutable acceptable for IO?

Tags: c++, io, constants, paint, mutable

Background: I am developing a UI Widget toolkit for experience, and a problem I ran across was with const-ness of events. All events are enforced as constant, therefore propagate of the same event between widgets will remain consistent.

This is ok for mouse events and key events; however, for paint events I fail to maintain const-ness because paint events inherently mutate whatever graphics context they are drawing upon.

In this example I'd like to create an mutable graphics context, so that the event itself remains constant. I realize the dangers of mutable so I'd like to hear reasons against mutable and alternatives to it if this is not acceptable.

For completeness, here is a sample of some of my code to illustrate the problem:

```
namespace event {
  struct Mouse {
    struct Interface {
      virtual ~Interface() = 0;

      virtual void on_l_press(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_l_release(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_l_click(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_l_drag(const Mouse&) {}

      virtual void on_m_press(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_m_releas(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_m_click(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_m_drag(const Mouse&) {}

      virtual void on_r_press(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_r_release(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_r_click(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_r_drag(const Mouse&) {}

      virtual void on_move(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_enter(const Mouse&) {}
      virtual void on_exit(const Mouse&) {}
    };

    gmt::Point<float> point = { -1, -1 };
  };

  struct Paint {
    struct Interface {
      virtual ~Interface() = 0;

      virtual void on_paint(const Paint&) {}
    };

    gmt::Rect<float> dirty;
    mutable gfx::Context context;
  };
}
```

I've heard of IO Monads in Haskell but I've not a lot of experience or understanding with them unfortunately.

Also as a small note, I realize the events should be classes with getters and setters. This is something I am planning to change once I have a better idea of finalizing events.

Comment: Why, in your design, does the act of painting a UI widget need to change the event object passed to it?   You describe that as an inherent requirement.  It is not - it is a "feature" of your design.  A paint event may cause the widget to change state (i.e. to update its display buffer and display) but the widget doesn't need to change the event data passed to it.

Comment: @Peter The widget itself may change, but I am trying to guarentee it will not change the paint event itself, hence a non-const function. The act of painting UI should not change the event object, which is why the event itself is const.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents a non-`const` function from accepting a const argument.   Such as `window->on_paint(Paint_Event)` can be non-`const` (so it can change the object pointed to by `window`) but accept a `const` argument (so it guarantees not to change `Paint_Event`).     You somehow seem to be conflating the two - you don't want the message to change, so the window function must be const.   If you fix that conceptual problem, no need for data to be tagged mutable.

Comment: @Peter Sorry I am not understanding. I thought that is what I had currently. The on_paint is a non-const function (hence no const after the prototype) but has a const event. Can you elaborate, sorry.

Comment: You're the one who is asking about mutable data, because somehow you need to mutate a const object.